# email not sending, no errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm using this simple code to try and send an email:

```
    try
    {
        MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();
        newMail.To.Add("me@mydomain.com");
        newMail.Subject = "test";
        newMail.Body = "test";
        newMail.From = new MailAddress("from@mydomain.com", "from");
        newMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient SmtpSender = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpSender.Send(newMail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

along with the below code in my web.config file:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="localhost" userName="me@mydomain.com" password="password" defaultCredentials="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

I run the page and it completes with no errors, but no email is sent.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've updated the code according to the many examples I've looked at and and am now using a local SMTP client called hMailServer. I've tested my hMailServer outside of ASP.Net and it does indeed send emails. However, using the new code above it still does not work and does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure no email was *sent*, or do you mean the email didn't arrive in your inbox?  There are lots of things that can go wrong with email, few of which have anything to do with the code.  What is the response from the SMTP server?  If you point this at a server you control for debugging (something like smtp4dev), what happens?

Comment: In particular, look at your Gmail sent box.

Comment: I just checked and there are no emails in the sent box.  Unfortunately I don't control a server for debugging.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that's not allowing that port to go out maybe?

Comment: I've also tried with port 25 which I doubt is being blocked because we have an smtp server.  I've tried using that in my code but same results; no errors, no email.

Comment: Try putting your `SmtpClient` instance into a `using` block as well. Also, are you doing any exception "handling"? Are you sure you would know if an exception had been thrown?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I've updated the code according to the many examples I've looked and and am now using a local SMTP client called hMailServer.  I've tested my hMailServer outside of ASP.Net and it does indeed send emails.  However, using the new code above it still does not work and does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: @Austin, do you have an SMTP server in your machine? Are you trying to send emails from a third hosting provider like GoDaddy? If yes, are you testing this code from your computer, or from the actual server?

Comment: How are you authenticating to your `localhost` MTA outside of ASP.Net? Your web config shows you are providing a uname and pwd, but set `defaultCredentials` as `true` (conflicting settings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting your email form elsewhere, you may need to "doctor up" who is doing the sending on your form.

GoDaddy, for one, will block emails from certain domains that they consider to be high SPAM sources (like GMail, Hotmail, and Yahoo! Mail).

To work around this, send your message from an email address that originates on your domain, preferably a fake one so you won't start getting tons of spam:

```
private const string mailer = "no-reply@yourDomain.com";
```

Go ahead and code in your webmaster address, for good measure:

```
private const string webmaster = "yourEmail@yourDomain.com";
```

When constructing your email message, your contact's email address should be specified in the **Reply-To** field (from `txtEmail.Text` in the code below):

```
lblError.Text = null;
using (var email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
  new MailAddress(mailer), new MailAddress(webmaster)) {
  email.ReplyTo = txtEmail.Text; // this comes off of your contact form
  string strHtmlBody =
    "<html><body style=\"background-color:#cccccc\">" +
    txtSubject.Text +
    "</body></html>";
  email.Subject = "Website Contact";
  email.Body = strHtmlBody;
  email.IsBodyHtml = true;
  var server = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
  try {
    server.Send(email);
  } catch (Exception err) {
    lblError.Text = err.Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: An article I wrote on it way back: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/65206/GoDaddy-Email-Form

Comment: Thanks, but I've updated the code.  I tried it using an internal smtp server and the problem remains.