# Information needed to send mail with C#?

Tags: c#, email, .net-3.5

I need to know what are all the possible things (passwords, port numbers, server ip addresses, protocols, attachments etc) that one needs to know to send an e-mail to any e-mail 
address using C# code. Please tell me what they are. Hopefully, I should be able to 
figure out all the coding myself.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20788933/153923

Comment: So much easier to just google "Send e-mail with C#".  Lots of tutorials/examples out there.

Comment: @Evanlewis - Google ? What is that ? How do I find this thing ? I already saw some examples. There is no comprehensive list of things needed in order to be able to send e-mails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these two pages. MSDN is a goldmine when you're looking for things that use C#

1. [MailMessage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And use this link if you want a basic [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/how-do-i-send-mail-using-c?forum=netfxnetcom).

Comment: trying this now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde